# Numeric is to number as X is to string. What is X?

Tags: single-word-requests

Synonyms are acceptable. In this context, "string" refers to a sequence of characters or letters (i.e. text).

Some initial suggestions: Stringwise? Textual?

Comment: Please give some context for the question - otherwise we're guessing in thin air.

Comment: If I could leave a one-word comment, that comment would be "stringy."

Answer (score 5):

*Numeric is to number as alphanumeric is to string*

**alphanumeric**

> 1:  consisting of both letters and numbers and often other symbols (as punctuation marks and mathematical symbols) ; also :  being a character in an alphanumeric system
>   2:  capable of using or displaying alphanumeric characters — [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alphanumeric)

This name complies with a number being regarded as a special case of a string.

**EDIT**: in programming world, *alphanumeric* often has a [narrower definition](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/alphanumeric-alphameric) than above e.g. only [Unicode letters or digits only](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlphanumeric(java.lang.CharSequence)).